# Display alert message after page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have to call  `$route.reload();` in controller 2 `addData` API call so that I can get the added data in my UI. But then the text 'Data added successfully' goes away due to page refresh.

**controller 1:**

```
  $rootScope.$on('reloaded', function(event, data) { 
         $scope.$parent.alerts.length=0;
         $scope.$parent.alerts.push({type: 'success',msg: 'Data added successfully'});
    });
```

**controller 2:**

```
 $scope.add = function() {
someAPIService.addData(JSON.stringify($scope.rows)).success(function(response) {
            ngDialog.close('ngdialog1');
            $route.reload();
            $rootScope.$emit('reloaded', "true");
        });
}
```

**HTML Part:**

```
<section>
     <div ng-controller="controller3">
     <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
     </div>

     <div class="row form-inline" ng-controller="controller2 as vm">
       <!-- Table data with text fields--> 
     </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="addDataDialog">

    <div id="frm" ng-controller="controller1" class="col-xm-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <!-- Labels with text fields--> 
    </div>

      <button class="ngdialog-button" ng-click="add()">Save</button>
    </div>
    </script>
    </section>
```

**NOTE:** Both controllers are in the same `JS` file and they are used for the same HTML file.

Comment: where `controller 1` lies? need html structure too

Comment: Why do you need `reload`? Maybe you can just update a `$scope`?

Comment: I think when you call the `$route.reload()`, the controller is immediately destroyed, so it will never reach the `$rootScope.$emit`

Comment: @k102 yes you are right..he need to call ajax for updating scope

Comment: @k102 - I need to reload because I am fetching the recently added data that is also manipulated a bit on server side. For example: created date is set only at server side so I want this to be displayed as well. So I need a reload.

Comment: @pankajparkar - I have updated the code. Also any way to do it with ajax in angularjs.

Comment: using `$http` call service its same as like ajax https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @pankajparkar - Many thanks. Following the link that you provided I am able to use ajax calls and am able to show alerts as well.

Comment: @pankajparkar - Hey! I though it will not be easy for you to write the answer and so I struggled myself and solved this. However if you provided it earlier I wasn't be so happier either as now I did it myself. So yes please. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78831/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-my-god).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to only load the latest record list which is on server side. Then there is not need to use `$route.reload();` after making post call. You need to only make ajax call to get the latest records list that will solve your problem. For making ajax you need to refer [**`$http`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> `$route.reload()` is getting used only when you need to load
>   controller again with specified template in your `$routeProvider` when
>   condition

Answer (score 0):

just a simple hint of an answer:

1. add a (specific) cookie (with javascript) before calling reload (use e.g [Cookies lib](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies)),
2. read it on reload,
3. and then delete it

Also you may use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if it is available instead of a cookie using same steps:

1. add a specific entry in local storage, before calling reload
2. read it on reload
3. and then delete it

Another option to maintain state client-side is to use url parameters but these will not do for page reload